# Proving that $Y= \{x_n \in \ell^2 : x_{2n} =0, n \in \mathbb N\}$ is closed and finding $Y^\bot$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, inner-products

**Exercise :**

> Show that the space 
>   $$Y= \{x_n \in \ell^2 : x_{2n} =0, n \in \mathbb N\}$$
>   is a closed subspace of $\ell^2$ and find the space $Y^\bot$.

**Attempt-Thoughts :**

First of all, the $\ell^2$ space is defined as :

$$\ell^2 = \Big\{x=(x_n) : \sum_{i=1}^nx^2_n<+ \infty\Big\} \; \; \text{with the norm} \; \; \|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^2_n}$$

Of course, $\ell^2$ is not only a Banach space, but also a Hilbert space equipped with the inner product : $$\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_\limits{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i$$

For proving that $Y$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^2$, I know that if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $Y \subseteq H$ then $Y \subseteq Y^{\bot\bot}$ and $Y=Y^{\bot\bot}$ if and only if $Y$ is a closed subspace of $H$.

Finally, the orthogonal complement of $Y \subseteq\ell^2$, is defined as :
$$Y^\bot = \{x \in \ell^2 : \langle x,y\rangle = 0, \forall y \in Y\}$$

I assume that finding $Y^\bot$ follows imediatelly by the fact that since $Y$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^2$ which is a Hilbert space, then $\ell^2$ can be written as :

$$\ell^2 = Y \oplus Y^\bot$$

**Question - Request :** Any help, tips, hints or thorough elaborations regarding the exercise and mostly the case of $Y$ being a closed subspace of $\ell^2$ which I do now know how to handle, would be very much appreciated !

Comment: Try letting $(y_m)_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $Y$ such that $y_m\to y$ in the $\ell^2$-norm. Why must $y$ be in $Y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $k\in\mathbb N$, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}\pi_k\colon&\ell^2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}&\mapsto&x_k.\end{array}$$Each $\pi_k$ is continuous and$$Y=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}{\pi_{2k}}^{-1}\bigl(\{0\}\bigr).$$Since each ${\pi_{2k}}^{-1}\bigl(\{0\}\bigr)$ is closed, $Y$ is closed.

The space $Y^\perp$ is the space $Z$ of all sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\ell^2$ such that $x_k=0$ whenever $k$ is odd. It is also clear that each element of $\ell^2$ can be written in one and only one way as the sum of an element of $Y$ and an element of $Z$. Therefore, $Z$ is indeed $Y^\perp$.

Comment: In my functional analysis studies, we cover only the real cases, so I assume nothing changes by just being $\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb C$, right ? Secondly, interesting approach and very fast as well ! Should there be any elaboration of why $\pi_k$ is continuous or is it considered as trivial as it seems ? Finally, my idea about "finding" $Y^\bot$ is solid ?

Comment: $\pi_k$ is not just continuous, but uniformly continuous. Consider that $$\lvert \pi_k(x)-\pi_k(y)\rvert^2\leq \| x-y\|_2^2$$ by definition.

Comment: Yes, it also works over $\mathbb R$. The function $\pi_k$ is continuous because$$\left\lvert\pi_k\bigl((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigr)-\pi_k\bigl((y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigr)\right\rvert\leqslant\left\lVert(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}-(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\right\rVert_2.$$Concerning $Y^\perp$, I will now edit my answer.

Comment: Also, it should be fairly clear how to prove that $Y^{\perp} = \{x_n\in \ell^2 : x_{2n-1} = 0, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs ! Well explained, appreciate it !

Comment: In your elaboration for $Y^\bot$ you indeed mean $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in\ell^\infty$ or you meant $\in \ell^2$ ? Sorry for poking.

Comment: I meant $\ell^2$. I've edited my answer.